# Homebrew : `Error: Cannot install in Homebrew on ARM processor in Intel default prefix (/usr/local)!`

Tags: homebrew

## Background

I followed [this](https://www.outcoldman.com/en/archive/2023/06/07/playing-diablo-4-on-macos/) guide (on using `Apple Game Porting Toolkit`), which stated:

> Even if you already have `Homebrew` installed on your macOS, it is probably installed for Apple Silicon. You need to install it for Intel architecture:

```
arch -x86_64 zsh

/bin/bash -c “$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)”

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:${PATH}"
```

## Issue

Now in new terminals, `brew` commands result in the message:

> **Error**: Cannot install in Homebrew on ARM processor in Intel default prefix (/usr/local)!
> Please create a new installation in /opt/homebrew using one of the
> "Alternative Installs" from:
> https://docs.brew.sh/Installation
> You can migrate your previously installed formula list with:
> brew bundle dump

unless I again run:

```
arch -x86_64 zsh
```

## Question

Is there a means to get `brew` going in its default form, but without breaking:

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:${PATH}" arch -x86_64 /usr/local/bin/gameportingtoolkit-no-hud ~/Games/battle-net  ~/Games/battle-net/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Battle.net/Battle.net\ Launcher.exe
```

?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [here](https://www.wisdomgeek.com/development/installing-intel-based-packages-using-homebrew-on-the-m1-mac/), I was able to edit (or create, if not existing) the file `~/.zshrc` (via `TextEdit.app` or the zsh `nano` command):

```
# ~/.zshrc

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"    # arm64e homebrew path (m1   )
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH" # x86_64 homebrew path (intel)

alias mbrew="arch -arm64e /opt/homebrew/bin/brew" # arm64e homebrew path (m1   )
alias ibrew="arch -x86_64 /usr/local/bin/brew"    # x86_64 homebrew path (intel)
```

The `export` commands ensure both `brew` commands can be found.
(*I think the M1 (`arm64e`) version would be the default because it's first in the order.*)

The `alias` commands allow the use of M1 `brew` (with `mbrew`) and intel `brew` (with `ibrew`).

After saving the zsh configuration  file (`~/.zshrc`), run:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

to enact the changes into the terminal.

**Note**: Use of `alias` was written by me, as specified by [here](https://linuxhandbook.com/zsh-aliases/).